# What is THRM temperature in HWMonitor?

Tags: home-server, temperature

I am bulding a server on Albatron motherboard. I don't have any specs yet.
CPU is reaching about 60C because CPU cooler is damaged.
Anyways what is THRM temperature in Hardware Monitor Pro? The THRM temperature reaches about 60C too.